# Stopping UINavigationController animating & resizing navigation bar when doing push segue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

I'm using [AMScrollingNavbar](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar) in iOS 7 to hide the navigation bar when scrolling in a `UITableView`, like Instagram does. However, when I tap on a cell's header to segue to the profile view controller (to show a user's profile), my `ProfileVC`'s navigation bar does a resize animation to 64px (44px navigation title bar + 20px status bar) and it's very noticeable. When I pop back to my `FeedTableVC`, the navigation bar maintains that 64px, and not the 20px (only the status bar) it originally had.

My question is: how do I stop the animation/resizing from happening? I'd like my `ProfileVC` to have 64px height, but it needs to perform it like Instagram does. If you tap a user's header, the profile view controller on Instagram does not do any resize animation - it just shows up having 64px height. Then when you pop back, the main feed still has 20px height if you scrolled in the table view prior to the segue.

A curious fact: The Facebook app implements this too. Should I keep using `UINavigationController` or is this what is doing the resize animation? I'm using segues via storyboard and my segue is called via `performSegueWithIdentifier:` (push segue).

Comment: I'm having this same issue with a custom VC.